# Как определить глобальные переменные в зависимости от запущенного скрипта в package.json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, package.json

В зависимости от того какой скрипт был запущен и какой конфигурационный файл будет задействован, мне надо определить глобальные переменные (шрифты и прочее).
Как узнать какой скрипт был запущен в package.json или как можно обратиться к ключам текущего конфигурационного файла?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прочесть из конфигурационного файла, который был задействован?

Comment: да,прочесть из конфигурационного файла

Comment: а почему бы не сделать несколько конфигов и не задействовать их в соответствии со "скриптом"?

Comment: я честно говоря плохо в этом разбираюсь, но как определить из какого именно config файла мне брать эти переменные, у меня есть конфигурационные файлы aerial.json и frisco.json и мне надо допустим вытащить из них свойство bacground,как мне определить из какого фала брать это свойство?

Comment: в таком случае видимо я задал не совсем корректный вопрос,меня скорее интересует  как я могу достать  свойства из конфигурационого файла который был задейсвован, просто изначально я думал определять какой скрипт был задействован и затем зафетчить данный конфиг файл и достать из него нужные мне ключи.

Comment: А ведь нормальные люди давно используют `.env` :\

Comment: да но настройки зависят от того какой конфиг файл был задействован, если я просто помещу свои глобальные переменные в .env файл то они будут одинаковы для каждого из проектов, или я что-то не понимаю?Вопрос в другом как определить какие настройки применять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотрите запущений скрипт, и в зависимости от того какой запущений - определяйте свои переменные

Comment: спасибо за лаконичный ответ

Comment: всегда пожалуйста

Comment: я ответил на ваш вопрос, теперь вы можете ответить на мой вопрос?

Comment: я вроде бы все сказал здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1195322/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9/1195479#1195479

Comment: нет, вы там не всё сказали

Comment: вы что теперь меня преследовать будете?)

Comment: что вы, совсем нет, я просто хочу получить ответ на вопрос