# Как влияет использование кастомных шрифтов в андроид приложении на его быстродействие/производительность?

Tags: android, шрифты

я использую 21 уровень api как минимальный и для подгрузки кастомных шрифтов библиотеку calligraphy, мне необходимо узнать как измениться быстродействие приложения, и насколько оно будет отличаться от использования стандартных шрифтов?

Comment: Ну сделайте два варианта да сравните.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте два варианта и сравните

Comment: каким образом??

Comment: Собираешь проект с кастомными шрифтами и без , сравниваешь

Comment: каким образом сравнивать?

Comment: по производительности )))

Comment: это вы указываете по какому критерию, я это в вопрсое указал,а я спрашиваю каким образрм сравнивать?

Comment: по критерию производительности програмы(то как быстро она работает если так ВАМ понятнее)

Comment: нет, мне так не понятнее)

Comment: как я могу вам помочь?

Comment: сказать каким образом сравнивать

Comment: ладно я вас понял , https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: вы меня не поняли, я знаю значение слова сравнивать, я спрашиваю каким образом мне сравнивать эти два проекта?)

Comment: а ну так скразу бы так написали, в чем проблема?

Comment: проблема в том что я не знаю каким образом сравнивать

Comment: а чем я могу вам помочь?

Comment: сказать каким образом сравнивать

Comment: я предлагаю сравнивать эти два проета по производительности

Comment: я знаю по каким критериям сравнивать, но я не знаю как это сделать?

Comment: Предлагаю посмотреть этот тред , там все подробно изложено https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1195322/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9/1195479#1195479

Comment: я просмотрел, но я не нашел там информации каким образом это сделать?)

Comment: зачем вы смотрели свой же тред?

Comment: потому что вы скинули мне его и сказали просмотреть

Comment: Вы сюда спорить со мной пришли или проблему решать?

Comment: решать проблемы, а вы как-то вообще не помогаете

Comment: я не помогаю, а может вы?

Comment: согласен, я сам себе не помогаю, но может быть вы поможете?

Comment: я бы помог если бы вы сказали что вам надо

Comment: прочитайте вопрос, тогда узнаете

Comment: в вашем вопросе много не нужной информации например зачем мне знать ваш апи и библиотеку

Comment: я думаю если вы пришли мне помогать, то вы скажете зачем вам знать эту информацию

Comment: то есть это квест пойми что у тебя хотели спросить?и какая информация тебе для этого понадобиться?)

Comment: нет, это вопрос, и если вы его поняли, то дайте на него ответ

Comment: зачем вы удаляете свои коментарии?

Comment: зачем вы следите за мной вам делать нечего?

Comment: так вы будете давать ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115517/discussion-on-answer-by-dmitry-------).